# New Component does not exist when in Workflow using Core Service

Tags: core-service, workflow

In Tridion 2011 SP1, I am trying to read a new Component using a Schema associated with workflow using this Core Service code:

```
ComponentData wfItem = client.Read(componentUri, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
```

I get the following error:

```
The item tcm:2-268-16 does not exist.
```

I also tried with tcm:2-268-16-v0 and got the same error.

Can I specify some magic ReadOptions to open it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me :) This is what I tried:

```
var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding {
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas {
        MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
        MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
    }
};

var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp");

using (var client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(netTcpBinding, remoteAddress)) {
    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
    ComponentData component = client.Read("tcm:21-990", readOptions) as ComponentData;
    Console.WriteLine("ComponentData: " + component.Title);
}
```

Using the code above, I executed it on several Components:

- new Component in workflow (with and without `-v0` at the end of the TCMURI);
- existing Component in Workflow (with and without `-v0`);
- new Component not in workflow;
- existing Component not in workflow;

I did execute the code as administrator and the Components in question were used by me. Maybe your case is different? and Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: Very good point about the user executing the code.  I suspect that is the case and will update soon with the result after testing.

Comment: We should add "who am I" to the gotchas list right after "where (in the BluePrint) am I?" ;-)

Comment: @Mihai, which version of Tridion did you test on?

Comment: 2011 SP1 HR1 (filler space)

Comment: So did you get it to work?